# Calculating rolling on a mixed date using groupby

Tags: python, lambda, group-by, rolling-computation, temp

I have to calculate number of days when temperature was more than 32 degree C, in last 30 days.
I am try  use rolling average. The issue is that number of days in a month varies.

`weather_2['highTemp_days'] = weather_2.groupby(['date','station'])['over32'].apply(lambda x: x.rolling(len('month')).sum())`

**weather_2**  has 66 stations
**date** varies from 1950 to 2020
**over32** is boolean data. If temp on that date is > 32 then 1 otherwise zero.
**month** is taken from the date data which is `weather_2['month'] = weather_2['date'].dt.month`

Answer (score 0):

I used this

`weather_2['highTemp_days'] = weather_2.groupby(['year','station'])['over32'].apply(lambda x: x.rolling(30).sum())`

This issue was I was grouping by date. That is why the answer  was wrong.